# How do you setup an ASP.Net 3.0 Core Web API project to use AutoFac and NLog?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, nlog, asp.net-core-3.0

I know that this question is requesting how to use two libraries, integrated into one .Net project, but after a lot of searching and article reading, I can't find anything specifically useful. Regardless, since setting up a logging dependency is a bit of a special case in ASP.Net Core, I think it's a good sample case to request on how to setup Autofac with a dependency example in an ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web API project.

I have a brand new, ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web API project (from the Visual Studio 2019 templates) and I need to add Autofac and NLog.

Autofac has documentation on setting itself up with ASP.Net Core 3.0, but since their examples use a standard Web project (complete with Razor and MVC setup), the structure of the project template is rather different than the basic ASP.Net Web API project. I can't figure out how to translate the web project information to my Web API project.

I think the majority of my problem is trying setup Autofac but since the first injected component I want to setup is a logger engine for ASP.Net Core, it seemed prudent to try and get the two to work together before trying to setup other components that I might write and which should be simpler to implement.

If anyone can provide some basic examples from within a brand new ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web API project showing how to properly setup Autofac and NLog, that would be helpful.  I'm not doing anything atypical or fancy and at the moment, my project is a brand new project created from the templates provided by Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: For NLog, check https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Comment: @Julian, I've been through that, but thanks.  I think NLog is properly setup, but it's getting it to work with Autofac.  I'm not sure if it's because I'm improperly setting up Autofac, or if I am properly setting up Autofac and not properly integrating NLog with it.  Thanks though.  I'm sure that's getting me close.

Comment: What did you try so far ? Did you check this doc : https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Yes, that document and the one Julian posted were the two main documents I could find.  However, when you create a new Web API project, the project, startup.cs & Program.cs files behave differently.  I couldn't figure out how to get Autofac to work with the Web API and I'm not sure if it's due to improper Autofac or NLog setup.

Comment: Could you share what you tried ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Not really, beyond high-level explanations. I've deleted and recreated this project multiple times. This is the first thing I've tried to do with this project. I basically want to create a new ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web API project using these two tools. But, specifically, I used VS19 to select the project type, then I created the NLog config file and then I primarily got stuck trying to decide how to setup Autfac. I've been guessing. There's a lot of documentation for .Net Core 2.0 and, in fact, I think I found documentation for Core 2.0, but it doesn't apply to the 3.0 changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *Program.cs* you should add the `.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())` method for *Autofac* and the `.UseNLog()` and `NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config")` for nlog.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog();
}
```

The `UseNLog` method will register things in the internal dependency injection and *Autofac* will use it. You don't have to do anything for NLog with Autofac thanks to this method.

In the *startup.cs* file you should add a `ConfigureContainer` method to configure *Autofac* but you don't have to do anything for NLog.

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // do whatever you want with Autofac 

    // you don't have to register anything for NLog 
    // the `UseNLog` method will register everything for you 

    builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>();
}
```

Comment: Ok, one quick question.  Where does `NLogBuilder` come from? I downloaded the NLog.Web package but intellisense isn't finding it and I get errors when I try to reference it.  No errors referencing NLog.Web from a using statement at the top of the file, though.

Comment: Package `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` as stated here https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#1-add-dependency-in-csproj-manually-or-using-nuget